# How to give and use htmlId for a field if a field is in field set

Tags: fieldsets

I am working on page where there are 5 fields in a field set . Now , I want to giv Id to a particular field in Field set and want to use $Component to get the field and run some Javascript function. Unfortunately, there is field set not the field. how can I provide ID to the field in the field set and use document.getElementById on that field to run Javascript function on it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can control the ID values. I suggest that instead you use the class of the elements to find them.

Here is an example:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.Test}" var="f">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact[f]}" styleClass="{!f}"/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:form>
<script>
function firstOfClass(className) {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    return els.length > 0 ? els[0] : null;
}
alert(firstOfClass('AssistantName').tagName);
</script>
</apex:page>
```

In this example I have a field set called "Test" defined that includes the field "AssistantName". You could include a loop counter value in the class name instead if you wanted the logic to work by index rather than field name.

The class does not have any CSS associated; it is just being used to mark the element so that the element can be found.